# MVC and EF randomly cause exceptions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a web application running on a deployment server that uses MVC5 and EF6.  I have the same version concurrently running on my development machine. I can make updates or add functionality and test it on the development machine and have no problems, then publish it to the deployment server and it will work fine.

From 2-8 days all of a sudden the system starts giving me entity validation errors, or giving me an error about changing an entities Id in a simple page that does nothing but load some entities and iterates through the list to display them.

To fix the problem I literally do nothing other than go back in to VS2013 and click publish...I don't change any code or settings...and it works again.

Anyone else have this problem or know what could be the cause?  Its not a complex web app and there are no background processes running.

Comment: Are you sure you're not just recycling the worker process?  Have you tried just doing that and not republishing?  Chances are, you have a memory leak somewhere.  Make sure you are not using any static DbContexts, or other static data that could cause corruptions (static items are shared across all users, and DbContexts in particular are not multi-user or thread-safe).  Also make sure you are disposing your contexts after each time you use them.

Comment: That is possible. There may have been some shared DbContexts in a few places, I'm currently rewriting a lot of the code to use the repository pattern where I'm using a Using block to ensure the DbContext is disposed after each page request.  I assume this will fix the problem if that is the cause?

Comment: If you had shared dbcontexts, then anything can happen, because two simultaneous users are writing over each others dbcontext.  What's more, the context will never be destroyed and will just keep allocating more and more memory until you start running out of memory, since dbcontexts have no mechanism to cleanup their memory usage other than disposing them.  They're designed to be short lived.  So yes, if that was the problem, then what you are doing will solve it...

Comment: would this also be the reason why when I run the site on the development server (but accessing the production SQL server) and then on the production server the data doesn't appear to show the updated values? I thought it was caching but I've turned off caching at all levels

Comment: Possibly, but its hard to know for sure... because one really can't know what is happening.